# How To create camera UI part of size 480*640 size in c# For Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

I have used this code for xaml .

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="640" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="160" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Canvas x:Name="viewfinderCanvas" Width="640" Height="480" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" >

        <!--Camera viewfinder -->
        <Canvas.Background>
            <VideoBrush x:Name="viewfinderBrush" />
        </Canvas.Background>
     </Canvas>

    <!--Button StackPanel to the right of viewfinder>-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" >
    <Button x:Name="ShutterButton" Content="SH" 
    Click="ShutterButton_Click"
    FontSize="26" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Height="75" />
    </StackPanel>

    <!--Used for debugging >-->
    <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,428,0,0"
    Name="txtDebug" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="626" FontSize="24"
    FontWeight="ExtraBold" />

</Grid>
```

But I have to create this in C#(at runtime).

I have tried much but but i am unable to find that how to use canvas to show image .
Please suggest me how to make it in runtime .

Comment: It's unclear what you want! 1) All this XAML code written in C#? 2) Video stream (picture) from camera showed on Canvas? 3) Capture picture on ShutterButton_Click and showing it on Canvas?

Answer (score 0):

To capture an image you can use the [camera task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394006%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), documentation linked. You also have the possibility to have a [deeper integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202973%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Those links should get you started. If you're running in more specific problems, ask (probably as a new question).